# MEF not recognising an export in Program Files(x86)

Tags: mef

I have an issue with MEF not exporting a plugin, apparently, only when installed in c:\Program Files(x86).

I am implementing a pretty straightforward MEF plugin system for a Windows service.

**Export for TestService.dll (plugin)**

```
[Export(typeof(IScheduledService))]
public class Service: IScheduledService
{ ... }
```

**Import**

```
public class ScheduledServices: IEnumerable<IScheduledService>
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(IScheduledService))]
    private List<IScheduledService> _services { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

**Composition**

```
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(PluginDirectory);
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
container.ComposeParts(pluginCollection);
```

This works fine in tests and driven through windows forms etc. It even works when installing as a service using "InstallUtil". However when rolled up into a windows setup and installed in C:\Program Files(x86) it doesn't pick up the export;

```
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition
'TestService.Service' was ignored because it contains no exports.
```

I'm thinking it must be related to some sort of CAS/Permissions ?

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

It might be where you are defining `PluginDirectory`. If you are using a relative path, e.g. `.\plugins`, it is likely using the service start path, which is not where you app is installed, but where `svchost.exe` is installed, at `C:\Windows\System32`. When I use MEF in services and want to use relative paths, I use something similar to:

```
private static readonly string CodeBase = typeof(MyService).Assembly.CodeBase;

public DirectoryCatalog GetCatalog(string relativePath)
{
  // Grab our codebase location as a Uri.
  Uri codeBase = new Uri(CodeBase);
  // Get the local path for the codebase.
  string path = codeBase.LocalPath.Substring(0, codeBase.LocalPath.LastIndexOf('\\');

  // Get the combined path
  path = Path.Combine(path, relativePath);

  return new DirectoryCatalog(path);
}
```

Where `MyService` is a type in the main assembly (the service assembly perhaps?). This ensures that I am always using the correct application path (which also supports Shadow Copying of assemblies).

Check how you are defining your `PluginDirectory` path.